# How to change text direction in less?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, right-to-left

I'm working on an RTL text document and I'd like to switch the display to RTL. The man page doesn't seem to mention anything regarding direction, only encoding.

P.S. I saw other less related questions here (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831681/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-less-gnu)), so I hope it's on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/) as such does not do this.  While it *can* work with UTF-8 (see [FAQ](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#intl)), RTL/LTR is a step further, and less portable. Actually ["BIDI"](http://sourceforge.net/p/mlterm/mailman/message/34379047/) may yield more possibilities than "RTL". But you have to pick through the possibilities. A web search for

```
less+pager+bidi
```

finds something that seems promising: [LESS-bidi - Direction agnostic stylesheets](https://github.com/danielkatz/less-bidi), but (for whatever reason) the name `LESS` is misleading since that only deals with CSS for a browser.  It has been dormant for nearly 3 years as well.

The [Translate Shell](https://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/) page implies it has a workable viewer for BIDI text.

Ubuntu lists a package [`bidiv`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/text/bidiv) which might be useful.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my question? I don't understand why was it down-voted